# How Spark’s HDFS I/O architecture is different from S3?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

Let’s say I have a regular Hadoop-Yarn-Spark cluster. When Spark reads a big file from HDFS, the file is split into multiple partitions and they are processed by executors on worker nodes. Each executor then is doing physical reads and writes to/from HDFS in the same cluster. Is this correct?

If so, then if I start processing remote S3 data and start reading from there - will only the spark master node do physical I/O (reads and writes) and then transmit the data to executors?

Comment: The file is already split in hdfs. No, why would that be the case for second question?

Comment: @thebluephantom Correct, the file is already split in HDFS. And each Spark worker/executor works on its own partition and reads from HDFS directly. My question when it comes to S3 - does each worker has its own access to S3 bucket where it knows which part of that bucket to read? Or it is the master that reads all the data and splits that data between workers?

Comment: Files can be read in parallel provided splittable. Master does some work but does not read all in afaik